# Elasticsearch return a strange result when adding fuzziness

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I'm working on an autocomplete search feature using elasticsearch. I finished it and it works fine. 
Current elasticsearch query:

```
array:2 [
  "index" => "hotels"
  "body" => array:3 [
    "from" => 0
    "size" => 5000
    "query" => array:1 [
      "multi_match" => array:3 [
        "fields" => array:2 [
          0 => "name.complete"
          1 => "name_ar.complete"
        ]
        "query" => "cairo"
        "type" => "best_fields"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

return the result below:

```
{
    "name": "cairo khan hotel",
},
{
    "name": "cairo city center hostel",
},
{
    "name": "cairo city center hotel",
},
```

But recently I was asked to find a way to correct the search keyword if the user has entered a wrong character. 
I googled it and I read about the fuzziness feature in elasticsearch, so I updated my code and added **'fuzziness' => 'auto'** to be like:

```
array:2 [
  "index" => "hotels"
  "body" => array:3 [
    "from" => 0
    "size" => 5000
    "query" => array:1 [
      "multi_match" => array:4 [
        "fields" => array:2 [
          0 => "name.complete"
          1 => "name_ar.complete"
        ]
        "query" => "cairo"
        "type" => "best_fields"

        "fuzziness" => "auto"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

but I got a strange result which looks like:

```
{
    "name": "caroline",
},
{
    "name": "carola - inh 29779",
},
{
    "name": "airo tower",
},
```

Any help to fix that, or accomplish such a thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a sample document with value for "name.complete" and name_ar.complete". Also add your mapping

Comment: Sure, here is the full code https://pastebin.com/0YyNuY5J  @jaspreetchahal